Verifying Zoom webhook using Google Apps Script - How to force Zoom webhook follow redirects?
I am trying to use a Google Script Web App to receive information from zoom through a webhook. I published my script as a web app and i can successfully receive the payloads from zoom, however to verify the URL i need to respond with a verification message and zoom keeps failing to verify the URL.
From some investigation I'm pretty sure the issue is that Content Service uses a redirect to serve the response and Zoom is waiting for a response from the same URL

I have seen some people on here, on the zoom forum, and on the google apps script forum suggest using HtmlOutput instead as a workaround but i can't figure out how to return the json data correctly using that method.
Original code for reference:
function doPost(e) {
  let token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  let data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let response = {}
  if(data.event=="endpoint.url_validation"){
    let plainToken = data.payload.plainToken
    let rawHash = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(plainToken, token);
    let txtHash = '';
    for (let j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
      let hashVal = rawHash[j];
      if (hashVal < 0)
        hashVal += 256; 
      if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
      txtHash += "0";
      txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
      }
    response = {
      plainToken: plainToken,
      encryptedToken: txtHash
    };
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

